# How can I extend the page height for my whole page in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to extend the page height in HTML be because I have a sidebar that needs the page to be taller because it has a lot of text in it and I don't want it to have overflow. How can I do that?

There is my code for CSS.
I tried adding a `html, body { height: 5000; }`
But it only extends the height of the main body part on the right side of the sidebar.
So how can I fix this?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 5000px;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 180px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  border-right: solid 1px #a7d7f9;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #0645ad;
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.wikiLogo {
  width: 135px;
}

.sidenavSubTitleVector {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(200, 204, 209, 0) 0, #c8ccd1 33%, #c8ccd1 66%, rgba(200, 204, 209, 0) 100%);
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  color: #54595d;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Rockstar Games</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="sidenav">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="wikiLogo" src="Images/wikiLogo.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <a href="#about">Main Page</a>
    <a href="#services">Contents</a>
    <a href="#clients">Current Events</a>
    <a href="#contact">Random Article</a>
    <a href="#contact">About Wikipedia</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact us</a>
    <a href="#contact">Donate</a>
    <div class="sidenavSubTitleVector">Contribute</div>
    <a href="#contact">Help</a>
    <a href="#contact">Learn to edit</a>
    <a href="#contact">Community portal</a>
    <a href="#contact">Recent changes</a>
    <a href="#contact">Upload file</a>
    <div class="sidenavSubTitleVector">Tools</div>
    <a href="#contact">What links here</a>
    <a href="#contact">Related changes</a>
    <a href="#contact">Special pages</a>
    <a href="#contact">Permanent link</a>
    <a href="#contact">Page information</a>
    <a href="#contact">Cite this page</a>
    <a href="#contact">Wikidata Item</a>
    <div class="sidenavSubTitleVector">Print/export</div>
    <a href="#contact">Downlaod as PDF</a>
    <a href="#contact">Printable version</a>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h2>Body</h2>
    <p>Body</p>
  </div>

  <script src="" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML? We need to see the whole picture.

Comment: I am unclear what you require as you have given the navbar position fixed. (Dependant on your HTML structure) this normally fixes it in the viewport so any text below that will never be seen.

Comment: I edited in the HTML code, hope that helps.

Comment: wow, you are still supporting IE 6, 7, 8, 9, 10...?

Comment: I don't think you can fit all the sidebar items without scroll...because the viewport height varies device to device..what you can do is set the html height to 100vh and set sidenav `overflow: scroll`

Comment: The scrollbar is "making the page taller." You can't physically make the device bigger. You have to add some sort of scrolling to your sidebar if you want it to be usable on multiple devices.

Comment: `body {min-height: 5000px} .side-nav {min-height: 100%}`? Kinda ridiculous

Answer (score -1):

I will like to suggest you make the image the background of the webpage and make the CSS of the background "repeat", then the website will depend on the content of the sidebar.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean could you please explain in further detail?